# How to express certainty in percents of probability?

Tags: expressions, phrase-choice

How could I express there's a 70 % chance I'm coming to an event in a shorter way? Would these two options sound natural?

> a) I'm coming on 70 %.
>
> b) I'm 70 % coming.

Comment: No! (b) sounds as though only 70% of your body will be there! You could say "I'm 70% sure I'll be able to come."

Comment: How do you _really_ know there's a 70 percent chance? That's a suspiciously exact figure. How is is calculated? Why not 60 or 80? If you mean 'better than fifty-fifty, but not completely certain', why not say that? 70 sounds like an empty figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some limited occasions where percentages or ratios of chance (or 'probability') can be abbreviated to just the statistic, without mentioning 'chance'. For example, if the chance was 50% either way then some people might say "*it's 50-50 whether I'm coming or not*". Also, it has become quite common in colloquial speech to tack '100%' onto the end of a statement as confirmation, ie "*I'm coming, 100%*".

Besides those specific idiomatic uses, it just doesn't sound right to quote a percentage unless you specify that you are speaking about a percentage of chance. I can only think to say "*there's a 70% chance I'm coming*". An alternative, although no shorter, would be "*it's 70% in favour of me coming*". The same is true if, rather than 'chance', you mean a percentage of surety.